# How do I handle single quotes inside a SQL query in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I am using a particular query for inserting records. It is going well. I am even fetching records with a select query. But my problem is that, if the record contains single quotes ' ', then it gives me this error:

```
> NOTE:You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
>     check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server 
>     version for the right syntax to use near 'B''' at line 1
```

The `SELECT` query is:

```
$result= mysql_query("SELECT s.name, 
                             s.sid as sid, 
                             s.category, 
                             p.name as pname 
                         FROM poet p 
                         INNER JOIN song s 
                            ON p.pid = s.pid 
                         WHERE s.name= '$sid'") or die(mysql_error());
```

What should I do to skip quotes problem in this. When I want quotes to insert in my records.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2665744/problem-storing-string-containing-quotes

Comment: Instead of inserting quotes into your records, you could rather place quotes around the text when you extract it from the database and display it.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is much worse than this -- what if someone enters the value `'; DROP TABLE poet; --`?  You need to use either `mysql_real_escape_string()` to escape the value, or use parametrized queries (with PDO, for example).

<sub>It's 2011, for crying out loud.  Why is SQL injection still a widespread problem?</sub>

Comment: Well... PHP's mysql extension has automatic protection from multiple queries but your point is still *very* valid

Comment: Yes, I intentionally don't bring that up because hopefully the example will scare the crap out of the developer and get them to pay attention.  ;)

Comment: There's plenty of other nasty things you can do in a single query. My favourite is injecting some `UNION` clauses

Comment: Indeed.  Unfortunately I lack the mental energy to come up with any at 4 AM, but feel free to add some here and I might add them to my answer (with credit, of course).

Comment: maybe: $sid = "' AND 1 = 2 UNION SELECT host, user, password, Grant_priv FROM mysql.user WHERE '' = '";

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape the data

```
$sid = mysql_real_escape_string($sid);
```

Answer (score 0):

use http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php function on your string to quote  "'" and other special symbols
Other way to prevent injection - use different connections (login-passwords) with different rights for inserting and selecting. In this case mysql_real_escape_string wi9ll work good

Comment: This one is deprecated and does not solve mysql injection. Have a look at the answer @cdhowie gave.

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string` doesn't either, under a very specific set of circumstances.  ;)